# how to store resultset in type and fetch in Oracle

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I am new for Oracle.I just want to capture the result of the selection in variable and then I want to use that variable for multiple operation on that data like we do in the Sql server using table variable.

I tried as below:

```
BEGIN
   DECLARE
      TYPE FullRecord IS RECORD (RNumber NUMBER);
      rec    FullRecord;
   BEGIN
      SELECT RNumber 
       INTO rec 
      FROM tableData;
   END;

END
```

;

Comment: lookup plsql table

Comment: my requirement is that resultset has multiple columns (around 15) and all are by joining the multiple table, so want to capture that data in procedure and that data would be used in whole procedure.

Comment: Yes. you can do all that with PLSQL table

Comment: it would be great if you would give me some link or inputs , to move ahead

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/PLS23/ch4.htm

Comment: hi , thanks for the input , I tried this one                                                  Begin
DECLARE
   TYPE FullRecord IS RECORD 
      ( RNumber   NUMBER
      ); 
rec FullRecord;
begin
      SELECT RNumber INTO rec
from tableData;
end;
end;   so when there is one record it is working but i have multiple records and i want to use that records like "select * from rec";  It would be highly appreciated if you would help me in this

Answer (score 2):

You need `BULK COLLECT`. See below:

```
DECLARE
      TYPE FullRecord1 IS RECORD (RNumber NUMBER);          
      TYPE FullRecord is table of FullRecord1 index by pls_integer;          
      rec    FullRecord;
BEGIN
      SELECT RNumber 
       BULK COLLECT INTO rec 
      FROM tableData;

   for i in 1..rec.count
   loop

    dbms_output.put_line(rec(i).RNumber);
   end loop;

END;
```

Read a much better explaination [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html)